# Find Dynamic Org Chart Library to integrate with Angular

Tags: angular, charts, orgchart, getorgchart

I am trying to find a organizational chart library that I can integrate with Angular.
Where I can add/delete nodes in the chart dynamically, like when I click on add button it shows a dialog box to enter details and add it.
Or when I delete a node it asks for confirmation of deletion.
I am trying to find such dynamic library from a day but unable to. Helpl!

Answer (score -1):

You can try [BALKAN OrgChartJS](https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS)

[This](https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/Angular) help article demosntrates how to use it in angular

[image]

Comment: Can somebody recommend a free and open-source library to do the job?

Comment: I think you can use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-org-chart

Comment: @ray and how to use it? I installed it via npm, like in the instruction, but then I have an error Unexpected module 'NgxOrgChartModule' declared by the module 'DashboardModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.